# How to configure GDM font hinting and anti-aliasing?

Tags: fonts, gdm, 17.10

Which files are used to configure the font rendering on the GDM login screen, and what are the fields that are used to change the hinting and anti-aliasing?

I am able to set the desktop font properties using gnome-tweak-tool.
I can also directly edit `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings.gschema.xml` and recompile the schema:

```
cd /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
sudo sed -i "s|<default>'slight'</default>|<default>'full'</default>|g" org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings.gschema.xml
sudo sed -i "s|<default>'grayscale'</default>|<default>'rgba'</default>|g" org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings.gschema.xml
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

Both work equally well for changing the desktop font properties (after logging in), but they have no effect on the GDM screen.

I have also looked at the files under `/usr/share/gdm` and `/etc/gdm3`, but there is nothing there to specify the GDM hinting and anti-aliasing font properties.

Finally, I checked out the official [GNOME Display Manager Reference Manual](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/index.html.en), but there is no information on specifying the GDM hinting and anti-aliasing font properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font rendering in Gnome Shell is a known issue with Wayland; see [Gnome Bug 645433 - gnome-shell's panel ignores font settings](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=645433).

Uncommenting the following line in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, forces GDM to use Xorg instead of Wayland.

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Once Wayland is disabled, the fonts on the the GDM login screen pick up default system-level antialiasing and hinting properties from `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`.

I had incorrectly assumed that, because I am using an Nvidia card, and I had explicitly selected the Xorg session from the login screen, GDM was *also* using Xorg.  Apparently, this is not the case.

After this fix, the GDM login screen looks fantastic, with sharp crisp fonts!

Remember, if you only change the font settings using *Gnome Tweak Tool* or *Dconf Editor*, they wont be available to GDM (since you haven't logged in yet). Therefore, configure your font settings system-wide using a configuration file in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`, and don't forget to compile your changes using `glib-compile-schemas`.

Comment: this makes wayland session inaccessible from gdm